# Connect to database depending upon arguments passed

Tags: grails, datasource

I want to connect to different database based on arguments passed during application start, I am planning to pass argument like

```
grails run-app -Ddbsource.name=db_one
```

So, in this case, the Datasource.groovy should look like this

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
    dbCreate = "update"
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DEV-SVR;databaseName=db_one"
}
```

It should also work for WAR, I am planning to pass arguments the same way like this

```
grails war -Ddbsource.name=db_one
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

command:

```
grails run-app -Ddbname=db_one
```

code:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
    dbCreate = "update"
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DEV-SVR;databaseName=${System.getenv('dbname')}"
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific.I need it to work for run-app as well as war for all environments.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the best solution is externalizing configuration.
You can do that easily by properly setting up your DataSource.groovy and Config.groovy files.

This is what our (relevant part of) DataSource.groovy looks like for all our apps (which are usually deployed to JBoss for production):

```
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            pooled = true
            dialect= "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
//            loggingSql = true
        }
    }
    test {
        test {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update"
                url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            }
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            dialect= "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            pooled = false
            jndiName = "java:/${appName}DS"
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration we set the datasource to be a JNDI resource at production, which will be configured in the app server, and we also setup connection pooling and common settings (driver, dialect) for the development environment.

Now, with Config.groovy you can easily make the app load the rest of the configuration for the connection in development from an external file, which is great since that way each developer can set her own database configuration and no user/password combination is ever sent to the source control system.

In fact, Config.groovy usually comes with something like this at the top (commented):

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                        "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

So, if your app name is 'myapp', your user is 'max', your user home is '/Users/max', it will try to load '/Users/max/.grails/myapp-config.properties' or '/Users/max/.grails/myapp-config.groovy'.

There you can set the rest of the needed parameters (or override them).
Example properties file:

```
dataSource.username=USERNAME
dataSource.password=PASSWORD
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1/DATABASE?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
```

As well, of course, of other configuration properties you might need through out your app for different reasons (not just database configuration).

I think you can easily tweak this configuration by modifying the given locations using environment variables passed the way you are trying to do. That way you only need to set a single environment variable. Maybe like:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-${System.getenv( 'dbname )}-config.properties",
                        "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-${System.getenv( 'dbname )}-config.groovy"]
```